# Question marks while fetching data from phpmyadmin in Python 3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, phpmyadmin

Hello I have win 10 Greece. I want to fetch same data (the path of a file) from mysql. The problem is while I retrieve the path instead of the name of the folder I came across with??????. A sample of the code is the following

```
import pymysql as MySQLdb


dbid = "client"
password = "pass"
database = "clients"
serverip = "192.168.168.150"
db = None
cur = None
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=serverip, user=dbid, passwd=password, db=database, connect_timeout=20)
    cur = db.cursor()
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    print("Cannot connect with the Data Base : "), e

query1 = "SELECT path FROM `instructions` WHERE clientmac ='%s'" % (str(5555))
try:
    row = None
    cur.execute(query1)
    db.commit()
    row = cur.fetchall()

except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    print("Problem while Executing query :", query1, "error : ", e)
print(row)
db.close()
cur.close()
```

Python 3 uses Unicode so I thing that the problem is not from python but from phpmyadmin. The field path is “utf8_general_ci”. Everything looks fine but why instead of 
`'C:\\Users\\Γιαννης\\Documents\\Arduino'` I am getting `'C:\\Users\\???????\\Documents\\Arduino'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I hat to but some additional coding before the execution of the query. I post the code below.

```
import pymysql as MySQLdb


dbid = "client"
password = "pass"
database = "clients"
serverip = "192.168.168.150"
socketip = "192.168.168.18"

db = None
cur = None
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=serverip, user=dbid, passwd=password, db=database, use_unicode=True, connect_timeout=20)
    cur = db.cursor()
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    print("Cannot connect with the Data Base : "), e
query1 = "SELECT path FROM `instructions` WHERE clientmac ='%s'" % (str(5555))

try:
    row = None
    db.set_charset('utf8')
    cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
    cur.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
    cur.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
    cur.execute(query1)
    db.commit()
    row = cur.fetchall()

except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    print("Problem while Executing query :", query1, "error : ", e)
print(row)
db.close()
cur.close()
```